# ssh config under cygwin

Tags: windows-7, bash, ssh, cygwin, openssh

I have Cygwin installed on Windows 7. I made default install. I would like to use ssh config file (~/.ssh/config) to set host and options for connecting.

Normal ssh command is not able to find the config while I try to connect: ssh host
If I explicitly specify config file, everything is OK: ssh -F ~/.ssh/config

I cannot found any option to set ssh client, something like /etc/ssh

Maybe ssh doesn't know where is my home folder? (I have set HOME environment variable to my home folder)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Install the `openssh` package and then run `ssh-host-config`. It will generate a "ssh_config" file in */etc/*.

Comment: He obviously already installed the opsnssh package.

Comment: This does not work. It generates an ssh_config file in /etc/ but ignores anything I put in it, just as it ignores anything I put in ~/.ssh/config . But it will read from /Users/<me>/.ssh/config which is not in my Cygwin home directory.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. I wanted to use **~/.ssh/config** because I was already using that directory for other applications and didn't want to maintain 2 copies. So creating an **/etc/ssh_config** directory wasn't the ideal solution.

As Fujimoto Youichi mentions, ssh looks at **/etc/passwd** for your home directory and not the **$HOME** environment variable.

The current cygwin versions (I'm using 2.6) no longer creates **/etc/passwd** as part of the install. However, it is easy to create a new one:

```
    mkpasswd -c -p "$(cygpath -H)" > /etc/passwd
```

- **-c** Adds the current user to the passwd file
- **-p "$(cygpath -H)"** Adds your current home directory

https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/mkpasswd.html has more details on the available flags.

I haven't looked at the code, but ssh's preference seems to be:

1. **/etc/ssh_config**
2. **~/.ssh/config**

So if you only want to use the ssh configuration information from **~/.ssh/config**, then be sure to delete **/etc/ssh_config**.

Also, be sure to open a new cygwin terminal window after making changes, for them to become available.

Comment: seems it's been relocated to /etc/defaults/ssh_config

Answer (score 3):

ssh command looks for its config file under home directory from /etc/passwd.
So setting HOME variable will not work.

There are many ways but we can fix it by simply making a symlink as follows.

ln -s ~ /home

Answer (score 2):

According to the accepted answer, by use command to initialize:

```
ssh-host-config
```

You can also create empty `/etc/ssh_config` in Cygwin, which will work same.

The `/etc/ssh_config` creating by `ssh-host-config` is also empty with all comment out lines.

---

#### Reload SSH with new config:

To effect config, you can just finish editing `/etc/ssh_config` without restart service.

Comment: How does this differ from the accepted answer?

Comment: I can not comment on it to further explain the principle and how to effect the ssh config.

Comment: You need to earn some reputation first. Try editing some badly formatted posts, or answering an *unanswered* question :-)

Comment: OK! I posted this answer because after checking the accepted answer, I did more survey on it. Thank you.

Comment: This is written so much better than the accepted answer. e.g. the accepted answer  talks of installing openssh which is ridiculous 'cos obviously it's already installed . This one is very to the point

Answer (score 0):

The other answers didn't work for me.  I just created c:\cygwin64\etc\ssh_config and pasted in the following default / example file:

```
# This is the ssh client system-wide configuration file.  See
# ssh_config(5) for more information.  This file provides defaults for
# users, and the values can be changed in per-user configuration files
# or on the command line.

# Configuration data is parsed as follows:
#  1. command line options
#  2. user-specific file
#  3. system-wide file
# Any configuration value is only changed the first time it is set.
# Thus, host-specific definitions should be at the beginning of the
# configuration file, and defaults at the end.

# Site-wide defaults for some commonly used options.  For a comprehensive
# list of available options, their meanings and defaults, please see the
# ssh_config(5) man page.

# Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
#   ForwardX11 no
#   RhostsRSAAuthentication no
#   RSAAuthentication yes
#   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#   BatchMode no
#   CheckHostIP yes
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
#   Port 22
#   Protocol 2,1
#   Cipher 3des
#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160
#   EscapeChar ~
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   PermitLocalCommand no
#   VisualHostKey no
#   ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com
#
#
Host *
    Port 22
```

Hope that helps the next person.

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin ssh expects the config to be in `/home/$USER`. But the home directory "~" in cygwin is `C:/Users/$USER`, indeed `/home` is empty. You can have both `C:/Users/$USER/.ssh` and `/home/$USER/.ssh` be valid paths, by creating a symlink:

```
ln -s ~ /home/$USER
```

Answer (score 0):

The currently accepted answer did not fix the problem for me. Instead I symlinked the `.ssh` directory from my Windows user account's home directory into my Cygwin user's home directory:

```
ln -s /cygdrive/c/Users/<MY-USER>/.ssh /home/<MY-USER>/.ssh
```